# How can i select multiple dates with ng2-bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, datepicker, ng2-bootstrap

I am using  [`ng2-boostrap datepicker`](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap) with my angular2 application. It works fine, i have an option to select this week dates when user select this week option.

I went through the documentations seems there is no way to enable the dates. how can i achieve the same?

```
**Calendar.component.ts:**
import { Component, Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'; 
@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'calendar',
    templateUrl: './calendar.component.html'
})
export class CalendarComponent{
   @Output() onDatePicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();  
  public fromDate:Date = new Date();    
  public toDate:Date = new Date();
  public closed : boolean;
  public status: string = "today"
  private events:Array<any>;
  private tomorrow:Date;
  dates = { startDate: this.fromDate, endDate: this.toDate , closed : this.closed};
  private afterTomorrow:Date;
  private formats:Array<string> = ['DD-MM-YYYY', 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'DD.MM.YYYY', 'shortDate'];
  private format = this.formats[0];
  private dateOptions:any = {
    formatYear: 'YY',
    startingDay: 1
  };
  private opened:boolean = false; 
  public constructor() {
    (this.tomorrow = new Date()).setDate(this.tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

  }
  public pickDate( ): void {
    this.dates = { startDate: this.fromDate, endDate: this.toDate , closed : false};
    this.onDatePicked.emit(this.dates);
 }      

}
```

**Calendar.component.html:**

```
  <datepicker [(ngModel)]="fromDate" (ngModelChange)="pickDate($event)" [showWeeks]="true"></datepicker>
```

Comment: You might wanna give https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-date-picker a shot, it allows selecting multiple dates. Here is a demo : https://vlio20.github.io/angular-datepicker/